# How to get number of weeks count from database table in sqlite3

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

How to get number of weeks count start from Sunday to Saturday in sqlite3 database table inserted dates

Date inserted in database

```
    2015-12-13
    2015-12-14
    2015-12-15
    2015-12-16
    2015-12-17
    2015-12-118
    '
    '
    '
    upto

2016-12-13
```

Almost a year data inserted in database
I need count weeks count's data inserted start from Sunday to Saturday

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: you want help in sqlite query or in Objective C logic ?

Comment: @CodeChanger Yes i need sqlite query in objective-c